# Transpose columns and rows dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I've tried to use information from similar subject but still can't cope with it.

I've got the data something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
|    date    | business_day | total  | number | number_2   |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 2018-04-03 |            1 | 325857 |      0 |      888   |
| 2018-04-04 |            2 | 196308 |      2 |      829   |
| 2018-04-05 |            3 | 434970 |      1 |      661   |
| 2018-04-06 |            4 | 665941 |      1 |     1135   |
| 2018-04-09 |            5 | 589334 |      0 |      837   |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

How can I transpose it when number of rows could be dynamic (inthis case   columns no), the final result should be like this:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
|     date     | 2018-04-03 | 2018-04-04 | 2018-04-05 | 2018-04-06 | 2018-04-09   |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
| business_day |          1 |          2 |          3 |          4 |          5   |
| total        |     325857 |     196308 |     434970 |     665941 |     589334   |
| number       |          0 |          2 |          1 |          1 |          0   |
| number_2     |        888 |        829 |        661 |       1135 |        837   |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: I've stocked with that, anyone?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I posted? Feel free to ask if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dynamic query that automatically creates all the columns for all `Date` values you can use dynamic SQL, but be aware of security problems (SQL injection etc.) of this approach!

Here is a sample script that dynamically generates a query with all the columns for your `Date`:

```
if OBJECT_ID('Test') is not null
    drop table [dbo].[Test]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]([date] datetime, business_day int, total int, number int, number_2 int) 

insert into [dbo].[Test] select '2018-04-03', 1, 325857, 0, 888 
insert into [dbo].[Test] select '2018-04-04', 2, 196308, 2, 829 
insert into [dbo].[Test] select '2018-04-05', 3, 434970, 1, 661 
insert into [dbo].[Test] select '2018-04-06', 4, 665941, 1, 1135 
insert into [dbo].[Test] select '2018-04-09', 5, 589334, 0, 837 

declare @dates nvarchar(max)='' --this variable holds all the dates that will become column names
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''   --this variable contains the TSQL dinamically generated

select @dates = @dates +  ', [' + CONVERT(char(10), [date],126)+  ']' from [dbo].[Test] 
set @dates = RIGHT(@dates, len(@dates)-2)

set @sql = @sql + 'select col as [date], ' + @dates
set @sql = @sql + 'from '
set @sql = @sql + '( '
set @sql = @sql + ' select [date] , col,val,ord '
set @sql = @sql + ' from [dbo].[Test] '
set @sql = @sql + ' CROSS APPLY ('
set @sql = @sql + '     VALUES (''business_day'',business_day, 1), '
set @sql = @sql + '            (''total'',total, 2), '
set @sql = @sql + '            (''number'',number, 3), '
set @sql = @sql + '            (''number_2'',number_2, 4) '
set @sql = @sql + ' )CS (COL,VAL,ORD) '
set @sql = @sql + ') src '
set @sql = @sql + 'pivot ( max(val) for [Date] in (' + @dates + ') ) piv '
set @sql = @sql + 'order by ord'

exec(@sql)
```

Here is the result of this statement:

[image]